# Shader.CreateGPUProgram - Performance Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

On my 3d car war mobile game, I was getting huge spikes on Shader.CreateGPUProgram as per Profiler mentioning:

[image]

I have imported environments and cars 3d models within my Unity project. I didn't changed any models shader or material, I keep all those as I received.

[image]

What is the solution for me? so I can improve the performance of the game.

Comment: Anyone help me into this? This solution is really necessary for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use ShaderVariantCollection, you can also check out WarmupAllShaders[ https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Shader.WarmupAllShaders.html ].

Comment: How to use ShaderVariantCollection? First time I was hearing about this. Can you give me more information so I can understand actually what I require to implement.